# TextMate with Skim, TextMate window regains focus

Tags: textmate

I'm using TextMate Version 1.5.11 and Skim Version 1.4.12.  When I typeset a file, the PDF loads in Skim and gets focus as desired, but immediately after that, the TextMate editing window regains focus.  Is it possible to make it so the editing window remains in the background, so the PDF is on top and focused after typesetting?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of [TextMate (2.0 beta 7)](https://api.textmate.org/downloads/release) Skim stays on top after typesetting if I use the following settings:

[image: LaTeX bundle preferences]

I highly recommend that you upgrade your version of TextMate. TextMate 1.5 is quite old and unmaintained. TextMate 2 is a [free upgrade](http://blog.macromates.com/2014/yosemite/) for most users of TextMate 1.x.

TextMate 2 also includes an up to date version of the [LaTeX bundle](http://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle). The new version of the bundle fixes some errors and introduces new features, such as support for `lualatex`. [Here](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/compare/textmate-1.x...master) is an overview of all changes to the bundle since the version that ships with TextMate 1.x was released.

Comment: Has TextMate 2.0 been released?  I only saw the beta on the Macromates website.

Comment: It is still in beta. However, the [download page](http://macromates.com/download) states that it is the recommended versions for current versions of OS X:

If you are on OS X 10.7 or later we strongly recommend using TextMate 2 despite the beta label, this just means that there are still more work planned.

For OS X 10.9 and later, TextMate 1.x is not suitable as it relies on system components no longer available.